# switch behaviour - java

Tags: java, switch-statement

Why doens't the following code throw a runtimeException?

```
public class Test2 extends Test {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] array = new char[]{'A', '\t', 'e', 'I', 'O', 'u', '\n', 'p'};

    int count = 0;
    for (char c : array) {
        switch (c) {
            case 'A':
                continue;
            case 'E':
                count++;
                break;
            case 'I':
                count++;
                continue;
            case 'o':
                break;
            case 'u':
                count++;
                continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("length of array: " + array.length);
    System.out.println("count= " + count);
}
```

}

notice that 'E' and 'e' isn't equal and it is in the switch.. The same for 'p'. 
It does compile and run en prints:
length of array: 8
count= 2

I completed my OCA certificate today and got the above question. But I can't figure out why it doesn't throw a runtime when 'e' or 'p' is checked.. This means there is an empty "default" in every switch or something?

Comment: Why would you expect it to throw an exception?

Comment: @JonSkeet see the question: "when 'e' or 'p' is checked" since they are not in the switch

Comment: offtop but I am lost in thought about different meaning break and continue in embeded in for switch

Comment: Well in a standard switch(without a loop above) you can't even declare a continue statement. But the break just "finishes" the switch and takes the next one in the loop (since there is no other code following the switch).

Comment: Different languages have very different behavours for “switch” statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This means there is an empty "default" in every switch or something?

Sort of. If no `case` matches the specified value, and there's no `default` case, nothing happens - it's as simple as that.

From [section 14.11 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11):

> If no `case` matches and there is no `default` label, then no further action is taken and the switch `statement` completes normally.

I wouldn't personally have *expected* an exception here - I don't think I've ever worked with a language which would throw an exception in a similar language construct, though I dare say one may exist.

Comment: I would actually find it a normal behaviour since the value passed through in a switch should, in my eyes, always be compatible with A case. And I understand it passes through, but why can it pass through?

Comment: @GregD: Well *sometimes* you want to view "it didn't match" as an error, and sometimes you don't. If you want to be explicit about it, you can choose to add a `default` case to every single `switch` statement you write.

Comment: Indeed. I thought the "default" was there to make 100% sure that every case is evaluate in the switch so that no RuntimeExceptions might be thrown (if no case matches the given value). I actually think I even read it somewhere sometime.. But it seems I was wrong there!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect any exception here? If value of `c` is not mentioned in any `case` statement nothing happens on current iteration of your loop, `switch` passes through and loop is going to the next iteration.

Comment: Then why does every checkstyle checker tell you to best implement a default case? Because it, in most cases, doesn't do anything useful. And why CAN it pass through..